# How to create a top divider in a menu on Android?

Tags: android, menu

I want to create a menu with dividers between groups (inside the menu) on Android. I have done it using different ID's for each group and it works fine.

Something like this:

```
+------------+
|   PHOTO    |
+------------+
| title Group|
+------------+
|   option1  |
+------------+
|   option2  |
+============+
| title Grp 2|
+------------+
|   option3  |
+------------+
```

Notice that `============` represents a divider between groups.

But I would like to have the menu as follows:

```
+------------+
|   PHOTO    |
+============+ <--- Divider also here
| title Group|
+------------+
|   option1  |
+------------+
|   option2  |
+============+
| title Grp 2|
+------------+
|   option3  |
+------------+
```

So I tried to implement a group with a hidden item at the top of the menu without luck because it does not display anything.

I also have tried adding a group with a "fake" text at the top of my menu. Like this:

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/invisibleGroup">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/invisible"
        android:title=" "/>
</group>
```

But now the menu is being displayed with a white space instead of only the divider:

```
+------------+
|   PHOTO    |
+------------+
|            | <--- Useless white space
+============+
| title Group|
+------------+
|   option1  |
+------------+
|   option2  |
+============+
| title Grp 2|
+------------+
|   option3  |
+------------+
```

So, how can I insert a divider at the top of the menu in a proper way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if there is some way to set a divider on the top of the menu but finally I found a way to insert a divider between the photo and the first group of options.

As I have included the XML in which the photo is contained before the menu on my `DrawerLayout` I have created a line under the photo in its XML file using a `View`.

This is the code that I have used to do that:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

It will give the feeling that there is a divider between the photo and the first group of options of the menu.